# Chopping lines in file for equal length but with new identifiers

Tags: perl

I have a file, whose every 2nd line is of unequal length. I want to make these lines equal(every 2nd line of output should be equal to 10 characters) but with new identifier (every odd line).

FILE ->

```
>ZQMK36301EDYQE
ZHZHHEXZZHHZZHHZZXHHHEHHHZZZHHHZHXZHZ
>ZQMK36301EEMJ9
ZZZXHZHHXHHHEZZEEZZHZZZZXEZ
>ZQMK36301EOEM5
ZXHXHZZHEHHHXZEZHXXXHXHHHHXEHHHZHHHH


desired output ->


>ZQMK36301EDYQE
ZHZHHEXZZH
>ZQMK36301EDYQE#2
HZZHHZZXHH
>ZQMK36301EDYQE#3
HEHHHZZZHH
>ZQMK36301EEMJ9
ZZZXHZHHXH
>ZQMK36301EEMJ9#2
HHEZZEEZZH
>ZQMK36301EOEM5
ZXHXHZZHEH
>ZQMK36301EOEM5#2
HHXZEZHXXX
>ZQMK36301EOEM5#3
HXHHHHXEHH
```

Here if we take the first line which is identifier (>ZQMK36301EDYQE) and in its 2nd line it contains 37 characters. Now it will make 3 sequences of equal length (i:e 10) and if remaining characters are less than 10, we will throw that part. Now each new line of equal length has an identifier which is same as from which the part of sequence it came but followed by "#" and the number. I want to do this for whole file. Please help.

Thanks and Best regards,
Vikas

Comment: On SO you are expected to have tried to solve the problem, and show your work.  Please read the [faq] and [ask] before posting.

Comment: I am really sorry for not telling what I have tried. I am new to Perl and stack-overflow and just trying to learn it slowly slowly. In my last posts, I have always given my tried code but for this, I was not even sure how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a one-liner:

```
perl -nwle '
     $i=0; 
     for my $add (<>=~/.{10}/g) { 
         printf "%s%s\n%s\n", $_, $i++ ? "#$i":"", $add; 
     }' inputfile
```

`-n` read file line-by-line and store line in `$_`. `-l` autochomps the input. We assume first line is header, and second is data. `$i` is the counter, so it is reset for each new line pair. The `for` loop list is made on the fly by reading one line `<>`, then extracting 10-character long strings from it with a regex. Then we just print the stuff, and make sure not to show the zero counter.

Comment: But I did not understand one thing, that how in this code you are telling Perl to cut every second line but not the identifiers?

Comment: You're welcome. `"..by reading one line <>.."` If you add the option `-MO=Deparse` you can get a better look at what happens.